# Rule conflict for protected branches in Github

Tags: github, branch, rules

I have multiple branches in Github repo and I wanted `force push` **not** be available for them ( So I chose branch name pattern to be * to include them all; The repo is dynamic and branches might be added later, so I set * to include all the possible future branches as well).

At the same time, I want my Master branch to have an additional rule :`Require pull request reviews before merging` enabled beside the rules that applies to all the branches, so I created another rule with **master** as the pattern and checked that box in there. But I'm given this conflict and I couldn't find what would be the outcome of this conflict:

[image]

I know that branch protection rule patterns are based on `fnmatch syntax` and I searched to see if there's a way to exclude master branch but couldn't find anything solid. Do you know if this conflict matters? And I'm not sure what would be the best practice to do it.

Comment: GitHub has a clear documentation on how the rule is picked when there are multiple rules matching the same branch: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/managing-a-branch-protection-rule#about-branch-protection-rules

Answer (score 1):

I tested this out and the conflict doesn't matter. Each branch may only have one branch protection rule.